# I am stuck thanks to ng-submit not working, it won't run when I click on it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, controller, angular1.6

I am taking an online course, and I am stuck on an assignment. In my assignment, I have a form and a form button that runs code when you click on a button. However,  my code does not run at all when I click on the submit button. Here is the nested div of my code where the problem is. I've edited stuff out, and kept all the information pertaining to my problem.

EDIT: I solved it, I found the problem. It started working once I changed ng-submit="contoller1.myFunction" to just ng-submit="myFunction()". It's kinda weird, but it works.

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as controller1">

        <div class="row row-content">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate name="myForm"  ng-submit="controller1.myFunction()">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Your Name</label>

                    <div>

                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>


                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">


                    <label for="commentField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comments</label>


                    <div>

                        <textarea class="form-control" id="commentField"  name="feedback" rows="12" required></textarea>

                    </div>

                </div>




                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Comment</button>


                        </div>



                </div>




            </form>

        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: This should work fine. That is exactly how `ng-submit` works. You don't need to add an `ng-click` to your submit button like one of the answers stated below. My guess is `controller1.myFunction()` is not being called for whatever reason. Hard to say without seeing all the code. If you do `ng-submit="true"` does the form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ng-submit on the form tag and change your button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.submit()">Submit Comment</button>
```

You'll also be needing the 'action' attribute on your form. And models on the inputs if you want to do something with the data (save, parse etc).

Comment: May I know why?? above code should work.. but he has to take care of inputs`s `ng-model`

Comment: I already have the ng-models in my code, I just removed them from my question because they're apart of an online assignment I am doing

Comment: Edited the answer, add 'action' to the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing ng-models on your  elements? ng-model is the data that gets passed between the client and the server.

Comment: I already have those, I removed them when I submitted the question because they're apart of an assignment for an online course I am doing.